# Trasladar datos de un archivo de cadenas de caracteres hacia un vector de registros de caracteres c++

Tags: c++, string, archivo, codeblocks

Hola estoy realizando una tarea la cual consiste en pasar datos de un archivo de texto, la cual contiene cadenas de caracteres, hacia un vector de registros (alumno) el cual tiene como única variable una cadena de caracteres, luego de recorrer los datos del archivo y almacenarlo me produce un error en la cual cuando imprimo la cadena de registros el primer elemento me sale como una cadena completa de todos los elementos que estaban en el archivo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX1 10 //Elementos que se ordenaran
#define MAXC 5 //Numero maximo de caracteres en una cadena
struct alumno{
  char nombre[MAXC];
};
void trasladorFileVectorCadena(FILE *f,alumno alum[],int *dx);
void MetodoSeleccionCadena(alumno alum[],int dx);
void ImplementarMetodoSeleccionCadenas(FILE *f,alumno alum[],int dx);
int main(){
   FILE *f;
   alumno alum[MAX1];
   int num_ele;
   ImplementarMetodoSeleccionCadenas(f,alum,num_ele);
   return (0);
}
void ImplementarMetodoSeleccionCadenas(FILE *f,alumno alum[],int dx){
   double secs;
   clock_t tini,tfin;
   trasladorFileVectorCadena(f,alum,&dx);
   for(int i=0;i<dx;i++){//El problema surge aquí
     printf("%s \n",alum[i].nombre);
   }
   printf("Iniciando metodo de ordenamiento de seleccion para cadenas...\n");
   tini = clock();
   MetodoSeleccionCadena(alum,dx);
   tfin = clock();
   secs = (double)(tfin-tini)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf("Tiempo necesario para implementacion de ordenamiento: %f\n", secs);
}
void MetodoSeleccionCadena(alumno alum[],int dx){
    int i,j,menor_pos,resp;
    char dato_menor[5];
    for(i=0;i<dx;i++){
        strcpy(dato_menor,alum[i].nombre);
        menor_pos = i;
        for(j=i+1;j<dx;j++){
            resp = strcmp(dato_menor,alum[j].nombre);
            if(resp==1){
                strcpy(dato_menor,alum[j].nombre);
                menor_pos = j;
            }
        }
        strcpy(alum[menor_pos].nombre,alum[i].nombre);
        strcpy(alum[i].nombre,dato_menor);
    }
}
void trasladorFileVectorCadena(FILE *f,alumno alum[],int *dx){
   char aux[6];
   int i=0;
   f = fopen("cadena3.txt","r");
   if(f==NULL){
      printf("El archivo no se puede abrir");
      exit(1);
   }
   
    fscanf(f,"%s",&aux);
    while(i<MAX1 && !feof(f)){
        strcpy(alum[i].nombre,aux);
        fscanf(f,"%s",&aux);
        i++;
    }
    *dx = i;
   fclose(f);
}
```

Al ejecutar el código sale el siguiente resultado

[image]

Lo que quiero es que salga de la siguiente manera :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido del archivo que estás leyendo?

Comment: Es un archivo de cadenas de caracteres separadas por salto de línea, todas las cadenas están compuestas por 5 caracteres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código es terrible, sólo describir todas las cosas que tu código tiene mal es más de la mitad de la respuesta. Pero empecemos por describir por qué tu programa se comporta de la manera que lo hace.

Tienes una formación<sup>1</sup> de alumnos, que tiene el siguiente aspecto en memoria:

```
alumno alum[MAX1]; // MAX1 es 10
```

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `alum[0]` | `alum[1]` | `alum[2]` | `alum[3]` | `alum[4]` | `alum[5]` | `alum[6]` | `alum[7]` | `alum[8]` | `alum[9]` |

Dado que cada alumno un objeto que contiene una formación de cinco caracteres, la distribución en memoria es esta:

```
struct alumno{
  char nombre[MAXC]; // MAXC es 5
};
```

| alum[0].nombre[0] | alum[0].nombre[1] | alum[0].nombre[2] | alum[0].nombre[3] | alum[0].nombre[4] | alum[1].nombre[0] | alum[1].nombre[1] | alum[1].nombre[2] | alum[1].nombre[3] | alum[1].nombre[4] | alum[2].nombre[0] | alum[2].nombre[1] | alum[2].nombre[2] | alum[2].nombre[3] | alum[2].nombre[4] | alum[3].nombre[0] | alum[3].nombre[1] | alum[3].nombre[2] | alum[3].nombre[3] | alum[3].nombre[4] | alum[4].nombre[0] | alum[4].nombre[1] | alum[4].nombre[2] | alum[4].nombre[3] | alum[4].nombre[4] | alum[5].nombre[0] | alum[5].nombre[1] | alum[5].nombre[2] | alum[5].nombre[3] | alum[5].nombre[4] | alum[6].nombre[0] | alum[6].nombre[1] | alum[6].nombre[2] | alum[6].nombre[3] | alum[6].nombre[4] | alum[7].nombre[0] | alum[7].nombre[1] | alum[7].nombre[2] | alum[7].nombre[3] | alum[7].nombre[4] | alum[8].nombre[0] | alum[8].nombre[1] | alum[8].nombre[2] | alum[8].nombre[3] | alum[8].nombre[4] | alum[9].nombre[0] | alum[9].nombre[1] | alum[9].nombre[2] | alum[9].nombre[3] | alum[9].nombre[4] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

La distribución de memoria no se diferencia de una cadena de 50 caracteres. Cuando imprimes una cadena con `printf`:

```
printf("%s \n",alum[i].nombre);
//      ^^ <---- Cadena
```

La función imprimirá caracteres hasta dar con un carácter nulo (`\0`), así que cuando pides imprimir el nombre del primer alumno, te imprime éste y todo lo que encuentra a continuación porque no hay un carácter nulo en el que parar... lo sorprendente es que no te imprima nada más después de "*oqlds*".

#### Solución.

La solución sería quemar todo tu código y escribirlo en C++ de verdad, pero si queremos ser menos drásticos bastará con que guardes espacio en `alumno::nombre` para el carácter nulo:

```
#define MAXC 5 + 1 // un carácter más para el finalizador de cadena
```

Y te tienes que asegurar de que inicializas a cero tu formación:

```
alumno alum[MAX1] {};
//                ^^ <--- Las llaves vacías inicializan todos los elementos a cero
```

#### La solución de verdad.

1. No uses `<stdio.h>`, `<time.h>` ni `<string.h>`, son cabeceras de C y estás programando en C++.
2. No uses `#define` para crear constantes, usa `constexpr`.
3. No uses formaciones de caracteres para guardar texto, usa `std::string`.
4. No uses `FILE` para leer archivos, esa es una herramienta de C, usa `std::ifstream` que es una herramienta de C++.
5. No uses `printf`, esa es una herramienta de C, usa `std::cout` que es una herramienta de C++.
6. Si una función recibe un parámetro con el único objetivo de pasarlo a otra función, es una pista de que dicha función no necesita ese parámetro. Lo estás haciendo con `f`, que la declaras en `main` pero la usas en `trasladorFileVectorCadena` tras hacerla pasar por `ImplementarMetodoSeleccionCadenas`.

Con esos cambios, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

constexpr std::size_t MAX1 10 //Elementos que se ordenaran

struct alumno{
  std::string nombre;
};

std::array<alumno, MAX1> trasladorFileVectorCadena(const std::string nombre_archivo);
void ImplementarMetodoSeleccionCadenas();

int main(){
   ImplementarMetodoSeleccionCadenas();
   return (0);
}

void ImplementarMetodoSeleccionCadenas(){
   for (const auto &alumno : trasladorFileVectorCadena("cadena3.txt")) {
        std::cout << alumno.nombre << '\n';
   }
}

std::array<alumno, MAX1> trasladorFileVectorCadena(const std::string nombre_archivo){
    std::array<alumno, MAX1> result{};
    int indice = 0;

    if (std::ifstream f{nombre_archivo})
    {
        std::string nombre;
        while (std::getline(f, nombre))
            result[indice++].nombre = nombre;
    }
    else
       std::cout << "El archivo no se puede abrir";

    return result;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, se solucionó el problema, voy a tener en cuenta las sugerencias que me brindaste :)